# Change app name in Prepare for submission status

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

- How to change app name in prepare for submission, by mistake i added extra character in app name how can i change the name and make it correct in prepare for submission?

is there any possibility to change the name?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the project settings, and change the `bundle display name`

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply but i am talking about app store app name. still app is in prepare for submission status on iTunes and i want to change the app name before put in review. how can i change the app name on iTunes connect.???

Answer (score 0):

cancel submit on itunes and make package again to change name.

Answer (score 0):

[image]open your itunes connect account
go to App information

in Localizable Information

change the name you want

Comment: if the app is submitted then app status will waiting for review not prepare for submission.

Comment: Hello @bobby i can not change as you said, i tried this before but it says that Entered app name already used,

Comment: @balkaransingh : still not submitted for review, my app is in prepare for submission status.